# Is Oauth2 really stateless?

Tags: session, oauth, jwt

As I know, JWT auth is definitely stateless, as a web server does not save any status of an user. However, Oauth2 is different. It stores each key of each user in an auth server, which means "stateful". No?

Answer (score 0):

> As I know, JWT auth is definitely stateless

No, JWT is not definitely stateless. It is just a format for signed/encrypted data and you still have to manage key materials to compute or use such token.

> OAuth2 is different

OAuth2 is a framework protocol. There is no notion of server "state" in the specification. But to ensure a high security level, the servers that implement that protocol should have to manage clients, initial access tokens, access tokens or refresh tokens, authorization codes...